# AttributeError: inkex.Effect instance has no attribute 'arg_parser'

Tags: python, inkscape

Im trying to develop a basic inkscape extension for educational purposes. I have been reading about it, and as far as I understand there is an old syntax and a new syntax, which the inkscape developers wants us to use. I have downloaded the inkex library from the main repository, but when I copy code from an extension developed with the new syntax it returns an error. On the other side, when I use the old syntax, copied from the inkscape source code itself it works perfectly. I would like to use the new one, as it seems a lot more intuitive and powerful.

My source code (new syntax):

```
class Scalefit(inkex.Effect):
     def __init__(self):
         inkex.Effect.__init__(self)
 
         self.arg_parser.add_argument('--prueba', action= 'store',
                 type = str, dest = 'prueba', default = 'prueba',
                 help= 'prueba')
```

Source code (old syntax, the one that works):

```
  class Scalefit(inkex.Effect):
      def __init__(self):
         inkex.Effect.__init__(self)
  
 
         self.OptionParser.add_option(
             "-x", "--width", type=float, default=32,
             help="The canvas width")
```

The most frustrating is that when I look on other extensions, they work perfectly with the same syntax.

Here is an example: https://github.com/KnoxMakers/KM-Laser/tree/master/extensions

Answer (score 1):

Try a different syntax:

```
class Scalefit(inkex.Effect):
    def add_arguments(self, pars):
        pars.add_argument('--prueba', default ='prueba', help='prueba')
```

See also:
https://gitlab.com/inkscape/extensions/-/blob/master/fractalize.py